# Trying to draw the schematic for a power divider circuit

Tags: ads, coupler

I want to draw both the schematic and layout for the following power divider circuit using microstrip lines in ADS. First of all I want to see if my schematic agrees well with theoretical results at all.

[image]

Here I have drawn the schematic. I'm not 100% confident whether I've ended up with the right schematic configuration to begin with. Particularly I'm not sure whether or should I need to use step junctions, junction Tees as required?

[image]

To check my schematic I did an S simulation and drew magnitude of S11 for comparison. The left shows my simulated result while the right depicts the result obtained from theoretical calculations given in [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7460975) paper. As you see it doesn't well agree with the theoretical results :(

[image]

Note that as far as S11 concerns the series connected R and C does not matter at all (a result verified by even- and odd-mode analysis given in the paper). So for simplicity I didn't include them in the schematic. So now I don't know what I should do to get as close as possible to the actual S11 response. What practical considerations have I missed?

Comment: *I'm not 100% confident whether I've ended up with the right schematic configuration to begin with.* I am 100% confident that **no one** can draw a correct lumped **element schematic** of the power splitter as the power splitter consists of many **distributed elements**. A schematic with many lumped elements can approach the same behavior but never be 100% identical. Tools exist that can extract an **S-parameter model** from the microstrip design which should give you a "close enough" model that can be used in some circuit simulators.

Comment: Quite few of us a) can analyze microwave transmission line circuits intuitively b) can access high end microwave circuit simulators. Maybe you should try something simpler to reveal possible fundamental errors. Try something that you can check theoretically by yourself or something which is well known and identical in several textbooks. BTW. You have simply joined together transmission line parts. I have no idea what  wave behaviour is assumed by default at those joints - maybe something unrealistic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the "lumped" microstrip components in microwave CAD tools used in the OP's schematic are generally pretty good for a first-pass design. I see no reason for them to not give a reasonable results when properly used, especially at these frequencies/dimensions. But yes, in general, you're right, real accuracy can only be obtained by a proper EM simulation.

Comment: Why are you using a zero-thickness conductor? Not necessarily relevant, but use a smaller step size for your S-parameter simulation (e.g. 0.1GHz instead of 1GHz) to give a cleaner plot

Comment: Took a closer look at the paper... the dimensions in your schematic are very different than the ones used in Table III of the paper. Any reason for that?

Comment: @Shamtam Yeah, they are off because I used Linecalc to find initial values for lengths and widths of microstrip lines. I wanted to start with a priori dimensions and then later modify them during EM simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected and as mentioned in the comments and user287001's answer, you should use the proper components to model any junctions in your microstrip lines, including any steps in line width, etc. In the case of this particular circuit, there's no good built-in microstrip component to model the junction where the split occurs, so that's something that would typically be EM simulated.

In any case, I think your dimensions are off... Using the dimensions from the paper and adding in the parallel \$Z_{ISO}\$ results in something reasonably close to the paper. See below schematic and plots. I simplified the short stub sections to a single MLIN and an ideal short to ground, which is not exactly what they do in the paper, but seems to be somewhat close to the results presented in Fig 7. of the paper. Note my use of an MCROS and an MTEE to model some of the microstrip junctions where the stubs connect. These are very important when working with the analytical transmission line models included in any commercial microwave CAD tool.

[image: schematic]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I doubted I'd need to use junctions in order to be precise. Also you used data in Table III which more likely were obtained using EM optimization. Figure 5 in the paper actually draws responses based on equations developed early in the beginning of the article. So it's obvious that our results will be off to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly you haven't got a flood of pro quality answers from advanced microwave designers. But here's a guess. It's essentially the same as I wrote as a comment.

Drawn joints between transmission line parts:

I guess the joint assumes some default wave behaviour. It can well be ok if the strip continues by having only a change of width. But three line joints should have some defined geometry. I have no access to high end design software, so this is only a guess.  I also guess you have at least thought the same when you wrote about maybe missing T-parts.

I suggest that you try to reveal possible fundamental error by trying something simpler which you can check by yourself or which is generally well known and presented identically in textbooks.

Comment: +1 for the good advice, though I don't think it's the particular issue in this case. In general though, the microstrip models in the CAD tools should be used to model all possible junctions.

Comment: +1 for your nice feedback. I'm certainly so eager to test it more in depth. But currently I'm short of time and will finally get back to it.